# How to insert date and time in Google spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

I would like to insert a custom date and time in the Google Spreadsheet single cell with custom formatting.

I am able to pick a custom format thanks to the post: https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2017/10/12/date-time-google-sheets/

But I am not able to insert a specific value that captures both date and time. The formula I am trying is something like: `=Date(2022, 2, 20, 04:08:53 PM)` and the desired output is something like: `Sun, Feb 20, 2022, 04:08:53 PM` but naturally it fails since the `=DATE()` API only takes in 3 parameters.

Is there some other API that helps capture both date and time?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `TIME` function:

```
=DATE(2022,2,20)+TIME(16,8,53)
```

or `TIMEVALUE`, if you enter time as string:

```
=DATE(2022,2,20)+TIMEVALUE("4:08:53 PM")
```

[image]